# Bundle or grouped product from configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product, grouped-products, manage-stock

*Note: I know this could be marked as duplicate as I have found many topics on this title.*

What I would like to know is how this e-shop is doing the stock management in this case https://www.totallywicked-eliquid.co.uk/10ml-tw-titan-fluid-10-bottle-multipack-product.html as customers only order one product (a 10ml 10 bottle pack) and each bottle has 2 configurable options:strength and flavour.

This looks like a Bundle of Configurable products however what they have there does not look like a built-in set of features from Magento.